# Cannot assign requested address with every port (Apache)

Tags: arch-linux, apache-httpd

I successfully installed and setup Apache server, and it works fine! I created a sysmlink for httpd service so it can startup on boot, and it works fine too!

Now if I lock my PC or put it on sleep, and unlock it again and try to visit localhost (or 127.0.0.1) it keeps loading forever!

If I try to run php server from command line, for eg, `php artisan serve`
It shows the error

```
Cannot assign requested address
```

[Error example](https://preview.redd.it/5dxctoou6v141.png?width=1366&format=png&auto=webp&s=a4315534eb1a1d881441430a0a2a020ed4aa7409)

I checked httpd service status and there are no errors shown and it's active (running)

Also any Jetbrain products stop working after that, it throw the same error upon starting!

The only way to solve this problem is to restart the whole pc which is very frustrating!

Comment: `lsof -i` must be run as root in order to display ports opened by somebody else. You can check which ports are already in use with `netstat -tulpn` or `ss -tulpn`. Also: How is your apache service configured and is this even necessary? You could use a [systemd/User](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User) unit to start the php server when you login?

Comment: @Stefan After hours of googling I couldn't found anything to fix this, I analyzed it and found out that if I put my laptop to sleep (with or without php server running) after unlocking again I just get this error! And not only this but I also get java nullpointerexception while opening any jetbrains app! The only fix I found is to reboot!